# Multiple Signaturepad Ionic with array

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello everyone I need your help I have a list of users and I want to everyone of them have a signature based on the users list, but I don't know how to make a multiple signature pad using ng For in ionic 3.

```
user1-signaturepad1
user2-signaturepad2
user3-signaturepad3
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please clarify more.

Comment: my question is ist possible to make a multiple signature-pad with ngFo.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to provide more clear direct question. For example: _"Is it possible to make a multiple signature-pad with ng For?"_

Comment: thankyou sir sorry again.